# Sort the big array according to the value of another array which is inside the big array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
     {  "result": true,     
         "users": [{        
                    "id": 11,   
                    "expected_count": 13,
                    "user_id": 1,   
                    "event_id": 2, 
                    "user": {       
                        "id": 1, 
                        "name": "Moiz Jamali"       
                     }  
           },
         {      
            "id": 12,   
            "expected_count": 12,
            "user_id": 2,
            "event_id": 2,      
            "user": {       
                      "id": 2,  
                      "name": "Juzer Samiwala"      
             }  
        }] 
}
```

Above the an output of my Big Array ('users').

What I want to do is sort this big array ('users') according to the name value which is inside the small array ('user') in PHP.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) for this. Something like this:

```
$bigArray = ["result" => true, "users" => [
    "id" => 11,
    "expected_count" => 13,
    "user_id" => 1,
    "event_id" => 2,
    "user" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Moiz Jamali"
    ],
    ... other users
]];

usort($bigArray['users'], function ($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['user']['name'], $b['user']['name']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to user [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with your own function to sort your array

**Solution :**

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{ "result": true, "users": [{ "id": 11, "expected_count": 13, "user_id": 1, "event_id": 2, "user": { "id": 1, "name": "Moiz Jamali" } }, { "id": 12, "expected_count": 12, "user_id": 2, "event_id": 2, "user": { "id": 2, "name": "Juzer Samiwala" } }] }');


function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->user->name == $b->user->name) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->user->name < $b->user->name) ? -1 : 1;
}


usort($data->users, "cmp");

print_r($data);
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/DIPcv)